# I want to replace / from path bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want replace / from the path /test/path/to/replace

i.e. the expected output should be =test=path=to=replace

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) -- What have you tried so far?  What were the results?  While your question can probably be answered as it is, it would be better if you let us know what you've tried already so that no one wastes their time and yours providing an answer that already hasn't worked for you.  Thanks!

Comment: Additionally: where does this path come from? From a regular file? From a program that prints it to stdout? Or is it stored in a shell variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

A="/test/path/to/replace"
B="${A////=}"
echo "$B"
```

Result:

```
=test=path=to=replace
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed command can be used here.

```
sed "s/\//=/g"
```

Command output examples:

```
pwd | sed "s/\//=/g"
echo "/test/path/to/replace" | sed "s/\//=/g"
```

File example (change "/" to "=" in text inside a file):

```
sed "s/\//=/g" file_name
```

Variable example (change content of variable; "/" to "="):

```
echo $var1 | sed "s/\//=/g"
```

Of course you can substitute "default" separator (slash sign "/") for, say minus sign "-"; in that case you avoid using backslash sign and get better readability:

```
sed "s-/-=-g"
```

Explanation (if some of you are not so familiar with sed command):

```
sed "s/\//=/g"
sed - stream editor (non-interactive command-line text editor)
s   - substitute sed command
/   - separators - first, third and fourth slash sign
\   - used for escaping second slash sign so that bash interprets second slash sign as litteral slash sign - not as separator)
/   - second slash sign; litteral slash sign (not separator) - term that we want to replace
=   - term that we want to get after replacement
g   - global sed command (replace all slashes, not just first one - without 'g' sed will replace only first slash in the path)


sed "-/-=-g"
All the same as in the previous explanation, except the two things:
1. We don't use escape sign (backslash) and
2. minus signs represent separators.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options.
You can use `tr`

`new_path=$(echo '/test/path/to/replace' | tr '/' '=')`

or `sed`

`new_path=$(echo '/test/path/to/replace' | sed 's/\//=/g')`